# What tools can I use to get better prices on a large list of parts on Bricklink?

Tags: shopping, bricklink

I prepared a long list of parts (Wanted List) that I want to buy using [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page). It is clear that I won't be able to get all the parts I need from a single seller and have identified three Bricklink stores that can cover the full list of parts I need.

What tools can I use to distribute the parts I need across the three stores to get the best prices?

Previously there have been tools like [Brick Wizard](http://thebrickwizard.com/) and [Brickficiency](http://www.buildingoutloud.com/brickficiency.php) but those do not seem to work with the updated Bricklink website. Are there currently any alternatives? I'm not shy to do some programming myself, but maybe there's a good starting point somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried BrickLink's own Easy Buy feature? You can select the Wanted Lists you want to work with, (or just select all your Wanted Lists), select some additional criteria (like store and shipping preferences) and BrickLink will automatically choose the cheapest combination for you. It's a really cool feature that can save you from a lot of manual searching and comparing.

Comment: Also, have you tried copying your wanted list over to BrickOwl.com (a competitor of BrickLink)? They also have an autobuy function where you pick vendors one by one and BO automatically picks the cheapest distribution of parts across the selected vendors. As an added bonus, BrickOwl takes shipping into account (BL typically does not).

Comment: @TheBrickBlogger For now I ended up distributing the parts I needed across three Bricklink stores manually. I briefly wanted to report on the Easy Buy feature. My manually sorted order totaled to 170 Euro including shipping, while the Easy Buy carts from two stores were 210 Euro without shipping. With one of the two shops that got selected, the feature also created a cart incompatible with the store's terms, not reaching the required minimum order total. From this anecdotal evidence, I can't really recommend the Easy Buy feature.

Comment: @MrCruelslyPants, I have had good success with Easy Buy, using a similar comparison method to yours. However, results sometimes do end up a bit out of whack, especially when the order is complicated with rare items. My preference is to use Easy Buy to get an idea how much my project would cost, and before I make the purchase, I double check with a manual or semi-manual method. For smaller orders of common items I would not hesitate to use Easy Buy by itself. For large, expensive, and/or complicated orders, I would double check manually.

Answer (score 1):

A new developer has updated Brickficiency to the new Bricklink API...

You can download it here: https://github.com/WindmillHelix/Brickficiency2/releases

I've tested it shortly, it seems to work as well as the old Brickficiency.
Haven't tested it well enough to check if it provides significant better options than Bricklinks own Easy Buy feature...

Just like the old Brickficiency, it's infeasible to process significantly long Wanted Lists as it uses a brute force approach (simply trying all store combinations)...